# How to improve the performance of a nuxt-vuetify page?

Tags: performance, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I built a website with nuxt-2 and vuetify. The main website page is "https://info-book.ir" and the page I want to improve its performance is "https://info-book.ir/tags/What%20is%20JavaScript%20and%20how%20we%20could%20learn%20JavaScript".

I checked that page in online tools and they give me some tips like the image below:

[image: performance error]

the main problem is loading resources that are related to **Vuetify** framework. I mean "Roboto google font" and "materialdesignicons.min.css" files. I don't know how to eliminate the effect of them in my project. They are necessary files and vuetify is using them by default. Is there any tricks that could help in this issue?

Also about the second problem, the **"js"** files are builted automatically by nuxt. I don't know how could I eliminate the effect of them when everything is done by nuxt and the setting that it has for building my project.

If any developer has any idea about that page and the way I could improve its performance, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You can get rid of the icon font by [using the SVG import](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-js-svg). With this, only the icons actually used appear in your bundle as pretty short SVG path strings.

Comment: @MoritzRingler Thanks for the comment. If you mean [this part](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons-js-svg) of the docs, I think if I want to implement that in my project, I must find all icons in all pages and change them. Is there any way to "defere" rendering of that font and "css" files only in that specific page (as the image suggested) in nuxt and vuetify, if I don't use them in that page?

Comment: You could look at the Vuetify component rendering the icon, see if you can get the import statement in there. But that is messy and probably worse than what happens currently.